# Can I be hacked just by watching a stream from a youtube channel that is being hacked?

Tags: phishing

A few days ago I joined a stream on a youtube channel that I later discovered was being hacked.
That got me thinking. Is it possible to have been infected with some type of virus just by accessing the stream (By this I mean that I didn't click on links or add. I just opened the stream on the youtube page)?

Comment: I'd say it's technically possible, but extremely unlikely unless you are dealing with an APT (advanced persistent threat), including government agencies. To really infect you just by watching a youtube video, I suppose the attacker would have to burn a pretty valuable zero-day.

Comment: What do you mean by "the channel was being hacked"?

Comment: While techincally feasible, the multiple encoding activities that happen on youtube's backend makes it unlikely. It would be far more likely that a malicious ad served via youtube exploited a vulnerability in your browser. Whether you could fine tune the ad parameters enough that it would only appear on one specific video or if the ad+video would have happened by chance can be debated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is feasible.

Do an internet search for something like "video decoder vulnerabilities h265". Plenty of vulnerabilities have been found and patched over the years.

The video stream is compressed with a video-specialised scheme. Different schemes are called codecs. Software code is used to decode the steam and therefore there is scope for errors and exploitation.

If someone uploads a video to YouTube that has a malicious payload, it would need to be unmodified by YouTube. They do reencode uploaded video, but perhaps not all the time: if the video substream is supported, they might send that out to viewers as is (even if a different container format is used). So this reencoding barrier may be the most difficult to overcome. But if a hacker was able to hack YouTube and directly deploy the malicious payloads that would be streamed, then that would suffice. Furthermore, of the reencoder is known, one could upload a payload that they know will be reencoder to their target malicious payload by YouTube.

Comment: "_They do reencode uploaded video, but perhaps not all the time_" That is a hypothesis you should prove.

Comment: @bradbury9 it would be nice to know for sure. The "perhaps" is important though because that could be a simpler attack vector than hacking YouTube.

Comment: I find it very unlikely, youtube analyzes the videos uploaded looking for copyright violations, so if the reencoding failed that analysis would have crashed due to different encodings long time ago and YT would have noticed.

Comment: @bradbury9 perhaps you have proof that YouTube always reencodes video? Unlikely. Consider: If the upload matches what YouTube users as the main video codec parameters, the upload engine may skip the reencoding step, being uneconomical. It's probably something that could be tested (upload then compare the hash off just the video stream upon download (excluding the video container), but then YouTube might change their implementation at some stage. So it is a "perhaps".